# Rational group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group scheme over a field $k$, i.e., $G$ is a functor from the category $\text{Alg}_k$ of unital commutative, associative $k$-algebras to the category of $\text{Groups}$. Suppose that $k[G]$ be the corresponding Hofp algebra, i.e., for $R\in\text{Alg}_k$, $G(R)={\rm{Hom}_{\text{Alg}_k}}(k[G],R)$.

**Question:** What is the definition of rational group scheme? (I looked into Waterhouse's book but did not find the definition). In particular, how to conclude that the group scheme ${\rm PGL}_1(A):={\rm GL}_1(A)/G_{m,k}$ embeds as an open subset in the projective space $\mathbb{P}(A)$? Here $A$ is a central simple algebra over $k$ and $GL_1(A)(R):=(A\otimes_k R)^*$.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what is a rational group scheme, but $\mathrm{PGL}_1(A)$ embeds into $\mathbb{P}(A)$ in an obvious way : $\mathrm{GL}_1(A)$ is  open in $A$ and stable under homotheties, hence $\mathrm{PGL}_1(A)$ is open in $(A\smallsetminus\{0\})/ \mathbb{G}_m=\mathbb{P}(A)$.

Comment: Perhaps rational group scheme just means that the underlying scheme is a rational variety (over $k$).

Comment: @abx, I think in above notation you mean $GL_1(A)(k)$ In that case argument is clear. ulrich, what would be the underlying scheme in the above example?